# Overlap I Agree Caption in jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin for i agree terms and conditions in the form as well as for fields, i implemented the form validation, but for i agree terms and conditions i noticed if the caption is in left side of checkbox it working properly, if i make the checkbox caption rightside, then the error message overlap now, if you can look into the demo of jsfiddle you can easily know about what i mean

Here is the code

```
<form id="genForm"  method="post" action="">
    <label>Email:<input name="Email" type="email" required></label>       
<br>    
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" required="required" />
        I accept the terms and conditions.</label>
    <br>
 <input class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x0wsq59p/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out myself with the help of documentation from jquery validate plugin with `errorPlacement` attributes.

```
<form id="genForm"  method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
<td>

    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" required="required" />
        I accept the terms and conditions.
      <div class="rerror"></div>
</td>
    </tr>
</table>


 <input class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the jQuery code is here

```
$("#genForm").validate({

 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

        console.log($(element).next());

        $(element).next().html(error);
    },

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7u6Lqhmo/

Hope it help someone :)

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your code a bit. Please make sure you close the tags in HTML properly.

HTML:

```
<form id="genForm"  method="post" action="">
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input name="Email" type="email" required="required"/>
            </li>                       
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" required="required" />
                <label>I accept the terms and conditions.</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input class="btn primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 50%     
}
label.error {
    float: right;
}
```

The code in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/x0wsq59p/12/